# .NET MAUI TabBar Handle Double Tap Gesture

Tags: c#, maui, .net-maui.shell

Using the TabBar Shell, is there a way to handle when the user double taps on a tab. In my instance I would like to allow the user to double tap the tab and this will cause a refresh on the contents of that tab.

```
<Shell xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Xaminals.Views"
       x:Class="Xaminals.AppShell">
    <TabBar>
       <Tab Title="Cats"
            Icon="cat.png">
           <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CatsPage}" />
       </Tab>
       <Tab Title="Dogs"
            Icon="dog.png">
           <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}" />
       </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

I'm using the example from .NET MAUI documentation to create tabs and would expect that there's a way to set a Tap Gesture Recognizer on the Tab.

Comment: I doubt that it is possible to do that. Did you try attaching a `TapGestureRecognizer` to the `Tab`? See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/tap?view=net-maui-7.0#create-a-tapgesturerecognizer You could set the `NumberOfTapsRequired="2"`. However, this might not work because it might be in conflict with the tap gesture of the Tab itself.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. 
`<Tab Title="Home"
            Icon="Icons/house.svg">
                <Tab.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"
                              NumberOfTapsRequired="2" />
                </Tab.GestureRecognizers>

            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
        </Tab>`